# Why doesn't MongoDb store my slashes in this string?

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone tell me why this command doesn't work from the MongoDB shell client:

```
db.coll.update({'live':true},{$set:{'mask':"\D\D\D\D\D\D\D\D"}},false,true)
```

but

```
db.coll.findOne({'id':'someId'})
```

returns the mask field as:

```
"mask" : "DDDDDDDD",
```

Where are the slashes going?

I've tried "double escaping" with \\D and that inserts both slashes:

```
"mask" : "\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D",
```

MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6, MongoDB version: 2.0.5, OSX Lion

Thanks

Comment: Could anyone leaving an example please ensure your own slashes are correctly escaped so I can avoid any confusion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex notation (without quotes)

```
/\D\D\D\D\D\D\D\D/
```

Or use four slashes.

```
"////D" ==> "/D"
```

Comment: I see. You are right. I didn't read the question well. Now this should work! :)

Comment: or without quotes (sorry) results in "mask" : /\D\D\D\D\D\D\D\D/,

Comment: That's fine. this is not an string. It's a  regex. you can get string of it with `toString()` method. You would have to trim slashes.
This is a workaround...

Comment: four of which slashes? four slashes in a string is interpreted literally.

Comment: It appears that the output in the shell is misleading. The slashes are correctly stored, escaped as \\ (double slash) and the client driver handles the escaping back to single slashes.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, MongoDB does properly store the backslashes in the database. What you're seeing is an artifact of how the mongo shell displays strings which contain the backslash character. It will print them as escape sequences rather than as single characters. If you look at the actual data that comes back, you'll see that it's correct.

```
> db.tst.drop()
true
> db.tst.insert({ _id: 1, str: "\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D"} );
> x = db.tst.findOne( {_id:1} );
{ "_id" : 1, "str" : "\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D" }     // looks like it's double-backslashes
> x.str;
\D\D\D\D\D     // but it's really not
x.str.quote();
"\\D\\D\\D\\D\\D"   // it's what String.quote() prints
```

Comment: Thanks, after checking the stored values in the client app I worked that out.

Comment: @RobDudley I think this is the better answer. Although it was posted a bit later, it's correct and explains the issue and what's happening. The accepted one is just 'use regex literal notation' which is just a nice tip

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of *nix and C creeping into everything.  In C, the character \ is the escape character.  If allows you to "escape" the next character or characters to form some special character or character sequence.  Thus, \n is newline (0x0a) and \d is carriage return (0x0d).  So, since \ has this special meaning, in order to get a \ you have to have two of them.

Change your string to "\D\D\D\D\D\D\D\D"

Comment: It wasn't clear in the original post (due to escaping issues!) but I've already tried double escaping the slashes and MongoDB then stores both slashes as per the 4th code block